# Constructor pattern and Object.create pattern effects on __proto__

Tags: javascript, constructor, creation-pattern

**Premise: I'm try to abbandon constructor pattern**

As you can see in looking at `console.log()` here

```js
//Constructor pattern
function F(){}

F.prototype.foo = null;

console.log(new F());

//Object create pattern
var FPrototype = {};

FPrototype.foo = null;

console.log(Object.create(FPrototype))
```

the object created by `Object.create` API has the `__proto__` properties referencing the prototype as `Object` while the one created by constructor has the `__proto__` prop referencing the prototype as the name of the constructor function.

I suppose that this behaviour is trying to simulate the strong typed langs, assuming that your constructor defines a new type identified by the constructor name itself.

That said, when my prototype chain grows I find very useful to identify different prototypes by name/"type", so is there any way to correctly have this using `Object.create` instead of constructor?

Comment: Yes, just add `FPrototype.constructor = F` to get a "typed" prototype.

Comment: @georg: as I understand the question, he doesn't want `FPrototype` to inherit from `F`, rather he wants an object created from `FPrototype` to be marked as inheriting from `FPrototype` in a debugger. Which is, as far as I know, impossible (it would require something like `FPrototype.constructor = FPrototype` but this of course doesn't work as expected).

Comment: @WiktorZychla: how about `FPrototype.constructor = function FPrototype() {};` then?

Comment: @georg: looks clever, haven't thought of redefining the `FPrototype` this way. Definitely looks better in the debugger, at least in Chrome. The newly created object still looks like `Object` but its prototype is now `FPrototype`.